# VueJS2: Control logic using JSON?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am a newbie to JavaScript. I am trying to figure out what is the best way to write the control logic for my application. I have a list of checkboxes that hide and show different elements depending on certain options that are checked.

> For example, I have the following HTML:

```
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="productType" value="magazines" v-model="selectedProductType"> Magazines 
     </label>
<label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="productType" value="books" v-model="selectedProductType"> Books 
     </label>
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="productType" value="comics" v-model="selectedProductType"> Comics 
 </label>
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="productType" value="videos" v-model="selectedProductType"> Videos 
 </label>
...snip...
```

> And then I am hiding/showing things based on the checkmarked items
>   above, like so **(this is just one example of some of the conditions I need to check)**:

```
<section v-if="(selectedOffice.jira) && (selectedProductType == 'comics') || (selectedProductType == 'videos')" id="booksInfo">Some info here</section>
...snip...
```

The issue is that I have to check different values in the data/model that looks like this:

```
//selectedOffice: '',
selectedProductType: [],
officeList: [
    {
        code: 'Blue Office',
        jira: true
    },
    {
        code: 'Red Office',
        jira: false
    }
...snip...
],

productList: [
    {
        type: 'comics',
        url: 'www.comicsurl.com'
    },
    {
        type: 'videos',
        url: 'www.videosurl.com'
    }

....snip...
]
```

Does anyone have any advice on the best way to approach the logic for my application? Better flexibility? My plan is to use an API for the data (Wordpress JSON REST API) and I will be able to customize the key/value properties on my own, but need help with the conditional stuff.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `v-model`, use `@click` or `v-on:click` to handle the click event instead. I like to keep most logic inside Vue instead of in the HTML so I recommend making use of `methods` and `computed` to determine what data to show.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedProductTypes: { 
      magazines: false, 
      books: false, 
      comics: false, 
      videos: false 
    },
    productList: [],
    typeList: [
      {
        type: 'magazines',
        name: 'Magazines',
        text: 'Check out new magazines'
      },
      {
        type: 'books',
        name: 'Books',
        text: 'Check out new books'
      },
      {
        type: 'comics',
        name: 'Comics',
        text: 'Check out new comics'
      },
      {
        type: 'videos',
        name: 'Videos',
        text: 'Check out new videos'
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    dataToBeShown() {
      return this.productList
        .filter(product => this.selectedProductTypes[product.type] === true) || [];
    }
  },
  created() {
    // get json data here
    // assignning data here for demo
    this.productList = [
      {
          type: 'magazines',
          url: 'www.magazineurl.com'
      },
      {
          type: 'books',
          url: 'www.booksurl.com'
      },
      {
          type: 'comics',
          url: 'www.comicsurl.com'
      },
      {
          type: 'videos',
          url: 'www.videosurl.com'
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    selectProductType(input) {
      this.selectedProductTypes[input] = !this.selectedProductTypes[input];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="control">
    <div v-for="item in typeList">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" @click="selectProductType(item.type)"> <b>{{item.name}}</b>&nbsp<span>{{item.text}}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <section v-for="item in dataToBeShown">
    <div>Type: {{item.type}}</div>
    <div>Url: {{item.url}}</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to let the user select more than one checkbox?

Comment: Sure, you can see I only used the `v-bind:checked` to prevent this, but by tweaking my code a little bit it's definitely possible.

Comment: that works good...last question: how do I add properties to the typeList object so I can display it in the checklist view? For example: [ ]magazines, download the latest! [ ]books, see the latest books! [ ] comics, see new comics!, etc....Where would I add "see the latest books!" text?

Comment: @redshift just add a new property and that's it, already modified the code.